# EF does not generate every model from database using SQLite

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I am trying to change the service based database in my project to SQLite. I am using EF database first approach but the EF does not generate every model from database. Eventhough foreign keys are set it does not generate the connections and also returns an error:

```
>     Error 6005: The data type '' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'Id' in the table 'main.Comments' was excluded.
```

It does so with every table that has an Id column (integer, primary key).

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You may have a column with no data type defined, change that.

Comment: I did check it, but the data type is defined. In every table where the id is integer and primary key, it does the same, and the model for that table is not generated.